# Calling for invoke func. from another class

Tags: vb.net, class, invoke

I have a server Form that receives data from a client.

I made a class that handles the client with a thread.

When I try to update the UI thread, I get a thread error.

```
Public Class Form1
    '...
End class

Public Class handleClient
    ' ...
    Dim ctThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf doChat)
                ctThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub doChat()
        While True
            Try
                Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
                Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}
                Dim bytes As Integer = networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
                Dim message As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)

                If Form1.InvokeRequired Then
                    Form1.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf addtxt))
                Else
                    addtxt()
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End While
    End Sub

    Sub addtxt()
        Form1.Text1.Text = Form1.Text1.Text & "sucsess" & vbCrLf
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using the default instance of `Form1` when testing `InvokeRequired`. Default instances are thread specific so that will always be `False`. You can read more about default instances [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html).

You can use any form or control to test `InvokeRequired` and call `Invoke`, as long as they were created on the UI thread. If your code is in a form or control that was created on the UI thread, you can just use the `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` members of that, i.e. `Me`.

If your code is not in a form or control then you can use the `SynchronizationContext` class. You need to create an instance of your class on the UI thread and, upon creation of that instance, you get the current `SynchronizationContext` instance, i.e. the one for the current thread. You can then use that instance to marshal back to that thread anywhere else in the code. In your case, that would look something like this:

```vb
Public Class ClientManager

    Private synchroniser As SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current

    Private Sub DoChat()
        '...

        synchroniser.Send(AddressOf DisplayText, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayText()
        '...
    End Sub

End Class
```

I've taken the liberty of improving the names of your type and members somewhat.

The `Send` method is synchronous, like `Invoke`, while the `Post` method is asynchronous, like `BeginInvoke`. Because `DisplayText` is executed on the UI thread, you can safely use the default instance of `Form1` there.

It's beyond the scope of this question but you really should not be updating a TextBox in a form from that code. You should call a method of the form and pass it the text, then it should update the `TextBox` from inside the form. Even better would be for that object to raise an event and have the form handle it, so that class doesn't even have to know that the form exists. That way, the form could be the one to marshal to the UI thread and you can go back to using `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid using the default form instance, you should. Then you can use an event from the class which is handled by the form. The class really shouldn't know the form exists.

Form1

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private myHandleClient As handleClient

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myHandleClient = New handleClient()
        AddHandler myHandleClient.UpdateStatus, AddressOf HandleUpdateStatus
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        myHandleClient.StartChat()
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleUpdateStatus(message As String)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(AddressOf HandleUpdateStatus, message)
        Else
            Me.Text1.Text &= message & vbCrLf
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

handleClient

```vb
Public Class handleClient

    Private ctThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf doChat)

    Public Event UpdateStatus(message As String)

    Public Sub StartChat()
        ctThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub doChat()
        While True
            Try
                RaiseEvent UpdateStatus("success")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End While
    End Sub

End Class
```